# Nextjs router.push slow page transition on first click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am using `next/router` to handle page transitions.

When a user clicks on a list of numbers from 1-4 on page `a`, I save the number they click via `localStorage` and reorder my list of numbers on page `b`.

For example, if the default order on page `a` is

```
1, 2, 3, 4
```

And the user clicks `4`

`next/router` send the user to page `b` with the changed order

```
4, 1, 2, 3
```

Below is my page `a` code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import { setLocalStorage } from '../../../utils/common'
import styles from './test.module.scss'

export default function NewHome() {
  const router = useRouter()
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
  const [order, setOrder] = useState([1, 2, 3, 4])

  const handleClick = (e): void => {
    let _order = order.filter((num) => num !== Number(e.target.id))
    setOrder([Number(e.target.id), ..._order])
    router.push('/renewal/test/b')
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const contact = { order }
    setLocalStorage(contact)
  }, [order])

  return (
    <div className={styles.a}>
      {numbers.map((number) =>
        <p id={String(number)} key={number} onClick={handleClick}>{number}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Below is my page `b` code

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { getLocalStorage } from '../../../utils/common'
import styles from './test.module.scss'

export default function NewHome() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    const _contact = getLocalStorage()
    setItems(_contact.order)
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className={styles.b}>
      {items.map((number) =>
        <p key={number}>{number}</p>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Below is my `localStorage` code

```
export const setLocalStorage = (contact) => {
  const _contact = getLocalStorage()
  const updateContact = {
    ..._contact,
    ...contact
  }
  window.localStorage.setItem('contact', JSON.stringify(updateContact))
}

export const getLocalStorage = () => {
  const contact = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('contact'))
  return contact
}
```

My problem is that when the user first clicks on any number on page `a`, there is a noticeable 1 second delay before the page transition to page `b`.

If I click the back button to go to page `a` from `b` and click on a number again, the delay is gone. But if I reload page `a` and try again, the 1 second delay returns.

I suspect

```
router.push('/renewal/test/b')
```

is causing the delay. But I am not sure if this entirely a nextjs issue, or a react issue, or a `localStorage` issue.

How can I reduce my 1 second delay when the user first transitions from page `a` to page `b`?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The above problem occurred on my development localhost server. Testing on production, the 1 second delay is gone.

Comment: i am using Nextjs 13 and its happening in production mode as well